# Error (10482): VHDL error: object "select_vector" is used but not declared

Tags: vhdl

I dont know why I am getting this error (Error (10482): VHDL error at SWSelectorVHDL.vhd(11): object "select_vector" is used but not declared). Please point out what do I need to change..
Here is my code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity SWSelectorVHDL is
generic(
NUM : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000" 
);  
port(       
selector    : in    select_vector(7 downto 0); 
rq      : in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
own     : out   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end entity SWSelectorVHDL;
architecture RTL of SWSelectorVHDL is
begin
gen_req : for i in 0 to 7 generate
requests(i) <= rq(i) when (selector(i) = NUM) else '0';
end generate;
end;
```

Comment: You also have an assignment to an undeclared signal (`requests`) and no assignment to `own`.

Comment: thanks. Just noticed..

Answer (score 3):

- I don't think "select_vector" is a valid type for your input port "selector". I guess it should be "std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)"
- or if "select_vector" is valid type then you need to include the package where you have declared the type "select_vector".

Comment: Thanks a lot..yes u are right. select_vector is not appearing in any colour like the other std_logic_vector. Just need a little information on what do you mean by package inclution. Do you mean another module where I need to define what is select vector or is it some special VHDL library that I need to install from internet!!

Comment: By package inclusion I meant to say, a package file containing your own collection of (if any) types, subtypes, functions, procedures, constants etc.