# Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at SWSelector.v(13): selector is not a constant

Tags: verilog

Referring to my previous post: 
[Error (10482): VHDL error: object "select_vector" is used but not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278598/error-10482-vhdl-error-object-select-vector-is-used-but-not-declared?noredirect=1#comment93443188_53278598)

I converted my code from VHDL to verilog, but I'm getting this error now:

> (Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at SWSelector.v(13): selector is not
>   a constant),

Any suggestions how do I deal with it?  There are 8 possibilities for selector switch which are coming from a decoder. So whenever the value of selector matches 3'b000, I want rq to be assigned to requests. Here is my code:

```
module SWSelector(
input [7:0] rq,
input [2:0] selector,
output [7:0] request
);
localparam NUM=3'b000;
generate
genvar i;
for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
    begin: label
    if(selector == NUM)
        begin
            assign request[i] = rq[i];
        end 
    else 
        begin
        assign request[i]=0;
        end
    end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `generate`?

Comment: @Serge VHDL does not stand for "Verilog HDL".

Comment: IEEE Std 1800-2017 27.3 Generate construct syntax "Generate schemes are evaluated during elaboration of the design. Although generate schemes use syntax that is similar to behavioral statements, it is important to recognize that they do not execute at simulation time. They are evaluated at elaboration time, and the result is determined before simulation begins. Therefore, all expressions in generate schemes shall be constant expressions, deterministic at elaboration time. For more details on elaboration, see 3.12." Your generate statement can't contain dynamic conditional elaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your if-statement is in a generate, you're asking the tool to pre-evaluate what `selector` is set to in order to figure out `selecter == NUM` evaluates to, but your tool doesn't know because it's a signal, not a parameter.

You want to use the generate to create an always block that you can check the value of `selector` in, like so:

```
module SWSelector(
    input [7:0] rq,
    input [2:0] selector,
    output reg [7:0] request
);
    localparam NUM=3'b000;
    generate
        genvar i;
        for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
        begin: label
            always @* begin
                if(selector == NUM)
                    request[i] = rq[i];
                else
                    request[i]=0;
            end
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

Or, as toolic said, you can use a ternary and an `assign`.

**Edit:**

Without generate:

```
module SWSelector(
    input [7:0] rq,
    input [2:0] selector,
    output reg [7:0] request
);
    localparam NUM=3'b000;

    integer i;
    always @* begin
        for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1) 
            if(selector == NUM)
                request[i] = rq[i];
            else
                request[i]=0;
     end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to use for loop without generate…? Because I dont even know why I am using generate! I just googled it and found that for loop has to be written under generate.. without generate for loop cannot be written.

Comment: Yes you can have a for loop without a generate, if you swap the for and the always block and get rid of the generate and rename the genvar and integer, that would work.

Comment: so basically, I need to use it under an always block... thanks... that helped me a lot…